# Deleting Rails Tables & Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

If the answer to this has already been discussed, please point me in the right direction. I have searched for this problem, but nothing I have found has worked in my case.

I've created tables that I would like to delete. I have deleted the models and the migrations, but when I attempt to recreate them then migrate, I get the following:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table already exists, etc....
```

I've attempted to use an `SQLite` manager to delete them manually, but I'm not sure where the database file is located (other posts didn't help me here either). I am on `Win 7`, by the way.

I would like to know the proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 7):

This is another easiest way of creating  table and migration again. If you are using rails 3. run this commands to drop database and create it again .

rake db:drop # to drop database

rake db:create # to create same database

rake db:migrate # to migrate the data.

Answer (score 4):

you can generate a migration

```
 rails generate migration DropProducts
```

and use it to drop the table

```
class DropProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :products    
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works to drop the table, but when I try to recreate and migrate, I still get SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: <then the SQL code>

Comment: @user2313155: The maybe you want to drop the `users` table as well. Or, if you're trying to restart completely, just delete the SQLite database file and start again.

Comment: I've gotten it working again. I'm actually not sure how. I just repeated my original process. I must have missed something the first hundred times.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog post on dealing with this kind of scenario, it may be helpful...

http://www.fmhcc.com.au/ruby/database-migrations-in-rails-and-when-to-start-from-scratch/